# Save the changes of ptrace() PTRACE_POKEDATA call

Tags: c++, operating-system, ptrace

I'm using `ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, addr, (orig ^ flip_mask));` in order to change a live process's data, but as soon as the call is terminated the changes that have been made disappear, would it be possible to keep the `PTRACE_POKETEXT` changes permanently even after terminating the `ptrace` call ?

```
void run_pro1 (pid_t child_pid) {
    srand(time(0));    
    int wait_status;
    unsigned icounter = 0;
    procmsg("debugger started\n");
    wait(&wait_status); 
    while (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status)) {
        icounter++;
        struct user_regs_struct regs;
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);       
        unsigned instr = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid,  regs.rax , 0);      
        unsigned *instr3 ;
        instr3 = &instr;                           
        unsigned instr2 = instr ^ (1UL << (1 << (rand()%32)));         
        ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, instr, instr2);        
        unsigned *instr4 ;
        instr4 = &instr2;        
        cout<<"addrctn="<< *instr3 <<endl;
        cout<<"addrctn="<< *instr4 <<endl; 
       if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, child_pid, 0, 0) < 0) {
            perror("ptrace");
            return;
        }        /* Wait for child to stop on its next instruction */
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);
        wait(&wait_status);             //break;      
    }   
    procmsg("the child executed %u instructions\n", icounter);
}
```

Comment: The changes shouldn't disappear.

Comment: The only reason it would disappear is because the process you poked reassigned the variable. You would have to change the code of the process to prevent that.

Comment: Can you show the code of the process you're tracing and how you're using `ptrace`?

Comment: Dear Barmar, thank you very much for your reply, I just posted the code for the tracer process tracing a child pid

Comment: What do you mean by "permanently"?

Comment: I meant the bit-flips that I'm injecting will be saved, so when I run again the child process it will still have flipped addresses giving wrong outputs as expected (trying to simulate space radiation effects)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem, I think, is that you are calling ptrace twice. The first time you pass it `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP`, which tells it to continue just one instruction. Immediately after, however, you call `PTRACE_CONT`, which tells it to continue until the next signal. The end result is that your program doesn't single step at all. It just runs.

There are a couple of secondary problems with your code. The first is that you are always calling these two functions with zero as the signal argument. Effectively, you are masking signals from the program.

Also, you are calling PEEK and POKE TEXT, and storing this in a variable called "instr". All of those don't make any difference, but they suggest you think you are dealing with instructions. The memory you read this from is from `rax`, which will rarely point at instructions, and might often not point at anything mapped at all. This, too, means you are probably doing something different than what you think you are doing, which is a probable cause of your problem.

Comment: Dear Shacshar, could you please write your suggestions in code, would really appreciate it, because I tried what you said but still the child process doesn't show any changes

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `POKETEXT` are wrong. The 3rd argument should be an address, but you gave `instr`, which is the old value, not the address from which it was read. To replace the value that you read, it should be:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, regs.rax, instr2);
```

Schachar Shemesh also has good points in his answer, but I think this addresses the specific problem you asked about.

Comment: Dear Barmar, I have tried your suggestion, but still the changes haven't been saved, the child process runs without problems

Comment: I don't know what the `RAX` register is used for, are you sure that's the right address to be poking?

Comment: I tried to modify the following registers:AL/AH/AX/EAX/RAX: Accumulator
BL/BH/BX/EBX/RBX: Base index (for use with arrays)
CL/CH/CX/ECX/RCX: Counter (for use with loops and strings)
DL/DH/DX/EDX/RDX: Extend the precision of the accumulator (e.g. combine 32-bit EAX and EDX for 64-bit integer operations in 32-bit code) .CS: Code
DS: Data
SS: Stack
ES: Extra data
FS: Extra data #2
GS: Extra data #3

Comment: If you want to modify the program, you should use the Program Counter register as the address.